# New to RoR, confused about where to put markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to RoR, moving from PHP. I have what I hope is a simple question.

Say I have a Model called **Article**, stored in the table **articles**.

If I want to display a list of articles on several pages in my site, I might have some simple markup such as;

```
<% Article.find_each do |article| %>
    <div class="article_list_wrapper">
        <h1><%= article.title %></h1>
        <p><%= article.body %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Where would I put this markup? I mean in what file; if I put it in a view, then I will have to copy it if I want a similar list in a different part of the site.

Putting it in the Model itself seems intuitive to me, the Article object should know how to render itself, right? But that seems totally against the CMV idea.

And what if I wanted to have several ways of rendering the same object? Like a list view, a full page view etc.

Many thanks, just trying to get into the correct habits from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would put that portion of HTML markup into what is known as a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) -- something that can be rendered as a small piece of a larger layout. You're right, you wouldn't want to store the format in the model, because you might wish to render that specific HTML for web browsers and render very similar XML or JSON for clients using an API and render some other very similar content into ASN.1 or YAML for further other clients. The "view" really should stay associated with the views.

With this specific example, you would probably go one further and provide the articles to render via a variable rather than letting the view find the articles itself:

Controller:

```
def flubber:
    @articles = Article.find_each(some_criteria)
end
```

View:

```
<div class="article_list_wrapper">
    <%= render :partial => "article_list", :collection => @articles %>
</div>
```

And then provide a View for the corresponding controller with the name `_article_list`:

```
    <h1><%= article.title %></h1>
    <p><%= article.body %></p>
```

If the `<div class="...">` is going to be identical in every single use of this partial, you could either pass a `:template` to the partial, or put it into a view helper, or put the entire render with the `:template` argument in a view helper. (Either the first or last approach here is what I'd do -- the `<div class="...">` doesn't seem so important to require its own *file*, but if it were more complicated, it might -- and then I wouldn't want to give the partial `:layout` argument every time I needed it.)

Comment: Great answer - but you should consider placing the partial in a shared folder inside your views folder then use '/shared/article_list' as your path to render the partial. Also consider using a before filter to get the articles list that you can make more use of caching the dataset to improve performance

Comment: thanks sarnold, that has cleared up a lot for me. and opened a bunch of new doors - more reading to be done.

Comment: @jamesw: both are excellent pieces of advice -- but I hesitated because lynks did say he was learning. [Fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) is definitely important for reasonable performance under load, but that might not be an issue. The shared folder hint is definitely wise if the partial is used in multiple controllers, but again -- simple assumptions here. :) Thanks for mentioning them both, though -- comments can excellently serve as footnotes. (And please don't hesitate to write your own answer; this advice is worth a +1. :)

Comment: @lynks: you might wish to wait a while before selecting my answer as The Accepted Answer. That marks the question "answered" and might reduce future good advice from other Stackers. Might as well wait a day or two. :)

Answer (score 1):

**MVC** (Model-View-Controller):
The Model has (primarily) the database piece and business logic.
The Controller controls application flow.
The View shows the info, e.g. the browser view.

So the markup you show which has a bunch of HTML goes in the view.
That is `app/models/views/article.rb`

The Controller is the part that gets the info.

You should actually have `@article = Article.all` in your controller and then just use `@article.each` instead of `Article.find_each` in your view.

If you have conditions you can apply them directly on the Controller find but the better approach is to learn about how you can use model finders with scopes and then use those scopes from the controller.  Always try and push things up from View to Controller to View and follow the 'fat Model, thin Controller' approach when practical.

For reuse partials can help but as better understanding of rails will help more.

See [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) by Ryan Bates. Incredible tutorials.

You might also like my own bookmarks for rails at my (rails) [linker](http://www.rormd.com/linker/groups/1) app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for this.